# Restoring an overwritten javascript method in IE8

Tags: javascript, debugging, methods, overriding, prototype

I override a number of methods on the `Element` prototype so I can add in a custom hook like so:

```
Element.prototype._method = Element.prototype.method;
Element.prototype.method = function(){
  this._method.apply(this, arguments);
  // custom callback
}
```

At some point, I want to restore the original method, so I do:

```
Element.prototype.method = Element.prototype._method;
```

However, when the `method` element is called on a node, it seems to throw a `Invalid procedure call or argument` error in IE8. Am I restoring the original method incorrectly?

Comment: +1 because it's an interesting question. However I suspect the real answer will be to rework your code and do things differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems IE8 has this issue and is not quite easy to resolve, but you could try `delete` on `Element.prototype` to restore an overwritten.

```
var old = Element.prototype.getElementsByTagName;
Element.prototype.getElementsByTagName = old;
// alert(document.body.getElementsByTagName('script').length); // this throws Error
delete Element.prototype.getElementsByTagName;
alert(document.body.getElementsByTagName('script').length); // Now it works as expected
```